# visibility setting of input submit buttons

Tags: php, html

I did a small experiment with the code below, which has a form containing an input submit button. I found that if I set the input submit button's visibility to visible, then it will not hide when I hide the form. However, if I set the input submit button's visibility to anything else, such as an empty string or something like "abcd", then it hides when I hide the form. Can anyone give me an explanation for this? Much appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            .sub
            {
                width: 100px;
                height: 40px;
                background-color: #1eaa28;
                cursor: pointer;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="POST" id="TestForm">
            <input type="submit" value="" id="TestButton" class="sub" style="visibility: abcd">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>

<?php                       
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>TestForm.style.visibility = \"hidden\"</script>";              

    // button hides if style="visibility: "

    // button does not hide if style="visibility: visible"

    // button does not hide if style="visibility: abcd"

?>
```

Comment: Do you mean `document.TestForm.style.visibility` as the selector instead? Alternative, use `document.getElementById('TestForm').style.visibility`.

Comment: although the above comment is accurate, you should not inject <script> tags to your code... just use javascript (see jQuery, it is fairly simple and it has nice selectors and hide() and show() functions)

Comment: @ied3vil There is really no need to load an entire library just to hide an element. Vanilla JS can do that just fine.

Comment: Well you either set the visibility with php inline or do that script tag thing... both versions are bad since mixing php and js is a bad practice. I've done that in the past. You should keep php and javascript separate as much as you can...